# Before submit hide section then resume

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a few buttons ... One of them needs to hide a section of the form before it's submitted so the requires are not blocking the submission. My problem is that after I hide the section, I can't seem to resume the form submission with the button click value ...

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="gstDemandesInscriptions.php?p=2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="entete">
        <a class="button" href="gstDemandesInscriptions.php?p=2">Retour</a>
        <button name="mod_cancel">Annuler la demande</button>
        <button name="mod">Enregistrer</button>
        <button name="mod_fact">Facturer</button>
        <button name="mod_term" onclick="beforeSubmit().submit();">Terminer (Ne pas facturer)</button>
    </div>

    <div id="facturation">
        Hide this part before submit
    </div>
</form>
```

I tryed a few things to get this working ... this is the last thing I tryed

```
onclick="beforeSubmit().submit();
```

The javascript for that is

```
beforeSubmit = function(){
    $("#facturation").hide();
}
```

What happens right now is that the div hides but the form does not resume submission ...

I tried adding

```
$("#myform").submit();
```

Inside the javascript but then the form is submited but with out the mod_term button value

I also tried

```
$(this).submit();
```

But that does not trigger anything

Comment: why you need to hide the button the website will go to the php page url immateriality?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the hide element function ,  just add attribute `value='_mod_term_VALUE'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
beforeSubmit = function(){ 
  $("#facturation").hide();
  $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'mod_term').attr('value', '1').appendTo('#myform');
  $('#myform').submit(); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" method="post" action="gstDemandesInscriptions.php?p=2" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="entete">
        <a class="button" href="gstDemandesInscriptions.php?p=2">Retour</a>
        <button type="button" name="mod_cancel">Annuler la demande</button>
        <button type="button" name="mod">Enregistrer</button>
        <button type="button" name="mod_fact">Facturer</button>
        <button type="button" name="mod_term" onclick="beforeSubmit().submit();">Terminer (Ne pas facturer)</button>
    </div>

    <div id="facturation">
        Hide this part before submit
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This is the first thing I tried. The div hides and the form submits but with out the button mod_term value so it skips the right form processing on the server side. What i would need is to be able to inform the submit() event the button name $("#myform").submit('button[name="mod_term"]'); but that does not work

Comment: Button don't have value. Add an <input type="hidden" name="mod_term" value="any"> into the form.

Comment: It does not need a value per say ... It just needs to be set. But this is a good idea ... let me try this out

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: It worked. Please edit your awnser with the following: beforeSubmit = function(){
        $("#facturation").hide();  
        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', 'mod_term').attr('value', '1').appendTo('#myform');
        $('#myform').submit();          
    }